# Controlling z labels in contourplot

Tags: r, lattice

I am trying to control how many z labels should be written in my contour plot plotted with `contourplot()` from the lattice library.
I have 30 contour lines but I only want the first 5 to be labelled. I tried a bunch of things like

```
contourplot(z ~ z+y, data=d3, cuts=30, font=3, xlab="x axis", ylab="y axis", scales=list(at=seq(2,10,by=2)))
contourplot(z ~ z+y, data=d3, cuts=30, font=3, xlab="x axis", ylab="y axis", at=seq(2,10,by=2))
```

but nothing works.

Also, is it possible to plot two `contourplot()` on the same graph? I tried

```
contourplot(z ~ z+y, data=d3, cuts=30)
par(new=T)
contourplot(z ~ z+y, data=d3, cuts=20)
```

but it's not working.
Thanks!

Comment: `par(new=TRUE)` works only with base graphics. lattice is a completely different graphic engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the `labels` as a character vector argument and set the last values with rep("", 5), so perhaps for the example you offered on an earlier question about contour

```
 x = seq(0, 10, by = 0.5)
 y = seq(0, 10, by = 0.5)
 z <- outer(x, y)
 d3 <- expand.grid(x=x,y=y); d3$z <- as.vector(z)
 contourplot(z~x+y, data=d3)
 # labeled '5'-'90'
 contourplot(z~x+y, data=d3, 
    at=seq(5,90, by=5),
    labels=c(seq(5,25, by=5),rep("", 16) ),
    main="Labels only at the first 5 contour lines")
 # contourplot seems to ignore 'extra' labels
 # c() will coerce the 'numeric' elements to 'character' if any others are 'character'
 ?contourplot   # and follow the link in the info about labels to ?panel.levelplot
```

[image: The second plot:]

Answer (score 6):

Here is my take:

```
library(lattice)
x <- rep(seq(-1.5,1.5,length=50),50)
y <- rep(seq(-1.5,1.5,length=50),rep(50,50))
z <- exp(-(x^2+y^2+x*y))

# here is default plot
lp1 <- contourplot(z~x*y)    

# here is an enhanced one
my.panel <- function(at, labels, ...) { 
    # draw odd and even contour lines with or without labels
    panel.contourplot(..., at=at[seq(1, length(at), 2)], col="blue", lty=2)
    panel.contourplot(..., at=at[seq(2, length(at), 2)], col="red",
                      labels=as.character(at[seq(2, length(at), 2)]))
} 

lp2 <- contourplot(z~x*y, panel=my.panel, at=seq(0.2, 0.8, by=0.2))
lp3 <- update(lp2, at=seq(0.2,0.8,by=0.1))
lp4 <- update(lp3, lwd=2, label.style="align")

library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(lp1, lp2, lp3, lp4)
```

[image]

You can adapt the custom `panel` function to best suit your needs (e.g. other scale for leveling the z-axis, color, etc.).