# contourplot color and labels options in Lattice for R

Tags: r, lattice

I am quite new to Lattice and I am stuck with some possibly basic coding. I am using shapefiles and geoTIFFS to produce maps of animals distribution and in particular I have:

- 1 x point shapefile
- 2 x  geoTIFF
- 1 x polygon shapefile

I am overlapping a levelplot of one of the geoTIFF (UD generated with adehabitatHR) with a contourplot of the same geoTIFF at specific intervals (percentile values), a contourplot of the second geoTIFF (depth raster from ETOPO2) for three specific values (-200, -1000 and -2000), the point shapefile (animal locations) and the polygon shapefile (land). All works fine but I need to change the font size of contour plot labels, their length (i.e. from 0.12315 to 0.123) and positioning for all the contourplots. For the depth contourplot I would like to change the style of each line in something like "continous line", "dashed line" and "point line", and for the contourplot of the UD I would like to change the color of each line using a yellow to red palette.

As far as I understand, I should use panel functions to implement these changes (e.g. [Controlling z labels in contourplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859422/controlling-z-labels-in-contourplot)) but i am not quite sure how to do it. Part of my code to generate the "plot":

```
aa <-
  quantile(
    UD_raster,
    probs = c(0.25, 0.75),
    type = 8,
    names = TRUE
  )
my.at <- c(aa[1], aa[2])
depth<-c(-100, -200, -2000)

levelplot(
  UD_raster,
  xlab = "",
  ylab = "",
  margin = FALSE,
  contour = FALSE,
  col.regions = viridis(100),
  main = "A",
  maxpixels = 2e5
) + layer(sp.polygons(Land, fill = "grey40", col = NA)) + layer(sp.points(locations, pts = 2, col = "red")) + contourplot(
  UD_raster,
  at = my.at,
  labels = TRUE,
  margin = FALSE
) + contourplot(
  ETOPO2,
  at = depth,
  labels = TRUE,
  margin = FALSE
)
```

A simplified image, with no UD layer and no point shapefile can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3gqhu70vt6fr2pp/Rplot.pdf?dl=0) and as you can see it is pretty messy. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

So far for the ETOPO2 countourplot I have solved by eliminating the labels and adding the argument *lty* to style the line. Because I can't figure out how to use *lty* with different values for each single line in my contour, I have replicated the contourplot function three times on the same surface, one for each contour I am interested into (this was easy because I only need three contours).

For the position, font and font size of the labels of the remaining contourplot I have used

```
labels = list(cex = 0.8, "verdana"),
  label.style = "flat"
```

To "shorten" the length of the labels I have used the function *round* where I specify to which decimal digit to round number.

So now my new code looks like:

```
aa <-
  quantile(
    UD_raster,
    probs = c(0.25, 0.75),
    type = 8,
    names = TRUE
  )
my.at <- c(aa[1], aa[2])
my.at <- round(my.at, 3)

levelplot(
  UD_raster,
  xlab = "",
  ylab = "",
  margin = FALSE,
  contour = FALSE,
  col.regions = viridis(100),
  main = "A",
  maxpixels = 2e5
) + layer(sp.polygons(Land, fill = "grey40", col = NA)) + layer(sp.points(positions, pts = 2, col = "red")) + contourplot(
  UD_raster,
  at = my.at,
  labels = list(cex = 0.8, "verdana"),
  label.style = "flat",
  margin = FALSE
) + contourplot(
  ETOPO2,
  at = -200,
  labels = FALSE,
  margin = FALSE,
  lty = 1,
  pretty = TRUE
) + contourplot(
  ETOPO2,
  at = -1000,
  labels = FALSE,
  margin = FALSE,
  lty = 2,
  pretty = TRUE
) + contourplot(
  ETOPO2,
  at = -2000,
  labels = FALSE,
  margin = FALSE,
  lty = 3,
  pretty = TRUE
)
```

As one could expect, it takes a bit longer to produce the plot. Still no idea on how to change the colors of the UD contourplot.